# Convert mysql insert query to eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hy everyone!

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO `user`
(
    `user_id`, `count`
)
SELECT 300, COUNT(*) + 1
FROM `user`
```

How can I convert this to Eloquent in Laravel?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this a valid working mysql query?

Comment: yes of course! I tested

Comment: You can use from laravel insertUsing 5.7 `DB::table('tabl_name')->insertUsing(['columns'], $select);`. Check this https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It worked for me**

*In \App\User.php*

```php
<?php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

*In \App\Http\Controllers\UsersController.php*

```php
<?php
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function store()
    {
        $user = \App\User::create([
            'user_id' => 300,
            'count' => \App\User::all()->count() + 1,
        ]);
        dd($user);
    }
}
```

**I recommended**

How about add the `autoIncrement` property to `count` column?

*In migration file(/databse/migrations/yyyy_mm_dd_his_create_users_table.php)*

```php
<?php
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->bigIncrements('count');
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this answer useful for you.